# Which ANOVA function use is correct in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, f-statistic

So, I am just a beginner in statistics and RStudio, and I still do not understand fully the full purpose of F-tests (beside hypothesis testing) and I recently started using anova() function from R documentation to assess which model explains response better. While I understand how I use f-distribution and p-value, I don't understand from here which one of these models is better, because it seems to give same result for switching between parameters in anova function (anova(fit_a, fit_d) and anova(fit_a, fit_d)).

[image]

The only difference I see here is in "Sum of Sq" and "Df" which are negative in one case and positive in another.

Comment: How is f1 related to a1 & a2? Is f1 nested within a1+a2?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is, I thought it was irrelevant in that case, but yes, it is.

Comment: You have discovered that when the order of subtraction of two quantities is reversed, the result is negated.  The models are identical.

Comment: So why do I get that the p-value is low in both directions? I also thought that representing predictors a1 and a2 as joined one predictor f1 (=a1+a2), would give worse results because it's lacking those two possibly significant predictors by themselfes (by t-test I saw the both are significant).

Comment: It's doing exactly the same test both times; that the smaller model is equivalent to the larger model it is nested within. If you list the two models in "backward" order (getting a negative change in sum of squares), R is still assuming that's what you intend to test.

Comment: Incidentally, whether or not it's nested really matters for the test being used -- it definitely assumes that the two models being compared are nested.

Comment: Ok, I am coming back because I try out couple of models with different important attributes. I experimented with fit1 = lm(y~1) and fit2 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3), and whenever I print out anova(fit1,fit2) or anova(fit2,fit1), I always get the same F-value, despite second model including less RSE in the result. What is the problem, to me it seems that anova() is symmetric in terms of f-statistics, which is something I refuse to believe.